# how to start Java NMT

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jvm, native-code, jcmd

I am trying to enable Native memory tracking in CMD with the below command.

```
  java -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=[off|summary|detail]
```

But getting an error like :

```
  'summary' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

operable program or batch file.

I also tried the below command:

```
  java -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=[off] and java -XX:NativeMemoryTracking= 
  [summary] and java -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=[detail]
```

But getting error like:

```
   Error occurred during initialization of VM
   Syntax error, expecting -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=[off|summary|detail]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[off|summary|detail]` means one of, so you have to use it in the following way:

```
java -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=off
```

or

```
java -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary
```

or

```
java -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=detail
```